# Can anyone show me how to do this without using loops?

Tags: python, functional-programming

If it is not possible to create this list without loops, I'd be content just to minimize the time it takes to create this list. The goal is to create a two-dimensional array with the filenames for 100 pdf files in each of 10 or so folders. Tell me what you think:

```
    foldernames = [ 
        'Named_folder00/',
        'Named_folder01/',
        'Named_folder02/',
        'Named_folder03/',
        'Named_folder04/',
        'Named_folder05/',
        'Named_folder06/',
        'Named_folder07/',
        'Named_folder08/',
        'Named_folder09/',
        ]

    pages = []
    for b in xrange(len(foldernames)):
        pg_temp = [
            foldernames[b] + 'title1',
            foldernames[b] + 'title2',
            foldernames[b] + 'title3'
            ]
        pg_temp += [ foldernames[b] + '0' + str(j) for j in xrange(1,10) ]
        pg_temp += [ foldernames[b] + str(k) for k in xrange(10,100) ]
        for c in xrange(len(pg_temp)):
            pg_temp[c] += '.pdf'
        pages.append(pg_temp)
```

Comment: What is `a` in this line: `for c in xrange(len(a)):`?

Comment: I'm assuming it should actually be `pg_temp`, from context.

Comment: I guess it's `pg_temp`. you could replace that `for` with a `map`. and you don't need two `range`s you can merge them.

Comment: Oops--yes that 'a' should have been 'pg_temp' --fixed now

Comment: Was `xrange(11,100)` intended to be `xrange(10,100)`?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered for the useful suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files = ['title1.pdf', 'title2.pdf', 'title3.pdf']
files += [ "%.2d.pdf" % j for j in range(1,100)]
pages = [[folder+file for file in files] for folder in foldernames]
```

Note: I have no idea how fast it is, didn't benchmark it.

Comment: can you use file as a variable name since it is a reserved word in python?

Comment: @futuristcorporation Yes, but you shouldn't. It's not a reserved word.

Comment: Actually, I think it's okay to use file.  The usual objection to using (e.g.) str as the name of a string is that you're going to want to use str-the-function later, and getting it from builtins is a nuisance.  But in the case of file, you always have open as an alternative (and in 3.2 there's no file in the first place.)

Comment: @Ben: scope is limited only in python3.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath How did I not know that? In that case it's even *worse* to name list comprehension variables so that they shadow builtins. :(

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to be functional, consider replacing the list comprehensions with equivalents using *map()*.  That transforms your code to:

```
pages = map(lambda foldername:
                map((foldername + 'title%d').__mod__, xrange(1,4)) +
                map((foldername + '%02d.pdf').__mod__, xrange(1,100)),
            foldernames)
```

Arguably, the new code is more readable as well as faster and functional.

Alternatively, the titles and pdfs can be precomputed and then combined with *foldernames* using [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [itertools.starmap](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), and str.__add__.  This should be the fastest version:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

titles = map('title%d'.__mod__, xrange(1, 4))
pdfs = map('%02d.pdf'.__mod__, xrange(1, 100))
pages = list(starmap(str.__add__, product(foldernames, (titles + pdfs))))
```

Comment: using `product` won't create that nested list structure.

Answer (score 2):

This can be quite easily done using [*itertools.product*](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
foldernames = ['Named_folder%02d/' % i for i in xrange(10)]
pagenames = ['title%d.pdf' % i for i in xrange(1,4)] + ['%02d.pdf' % i for i in xrange(1,100)]
pages = map("".join, product(foldernames,pagenames))
```

Comment: `lambda x: "".join(x)` can be replaced by `''.join`.

Comment: @DSM: yes, I saw it myself when I shortened my code in general, thanks for noticing :)

Comment: This solution is *very* fast and nicely written.  Nice work :-)

Comment: using `product` won't create that nested list structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ["title%d" % i for i in xrange(1,4)] + ["%02d" % i for i in xrange(1,100)]  
pages = [["Named_folder%02d/%s.pdf" % (i,j) for j in x] for i in xrange(10)]
```